# How does the cycle structure of a sub-set of permutations change under a particular mapping?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, normal-distribution, permutation-cycles, moment-problem

Let $n \ge 1$ be an integer. Denote by $\Pi^n $ the group of permutations of $\left\{1,\cdots,n\right\}$ and by $\Pi^{(2)}_{2n}$ the subset of all permutations of $\{1,\cdots, 2n \}$ that are composed of cycles of length two only. For the later there are $(2n-1)!!$ such permutations. Now, in that space of those permutations we define a certain mapping as follows:

\begin{equation}
\Pi^{(2)}_{2 n}  \ni \sigma \longrightarrow (\sigma^1, \sigma^2) \in \Pi^n \times \Pi^n
\end{equation}

where $\sigma^{\xi+1} : (\lfloor (\sigma_{j,1}-\xi)/2 \rfloor + 1) \rightarrow (\lfloor (\sigma_{j,2}-\xi)/2 \rfloor + 1)$ for $j=1,\cdots,n$ and $\xi=0,1$. Here $\sigma_{j} := (\sigma_{j,1},\sigma_{j,2})$ is the $j$th cycle of the permutation $\sigma$.
What we really mean by the notation is that for a given $\xi$ we consider a set of pairs $\left\{ (\lfloor (\sigma_{j,1}-\xi)/2 \rfloor + 1), (\lfloor (\sigma_{j,2}-\xi)/2 \rfloor + 1)\right\}_{j=1}^n $ and we rewrite it as ${\mathcal S}:=\left\{ j, \sigma^{\xi+1}_j \right\}_{j=1}^n $ reversing each pair if needed. This is done in a recursive way as follows. For each $j=1,\cdots,n$ out of the original sequence of pairs we select all the pairs that contain the number $j$ and swap them so that that number sits at the first position. There can be at most two such pairs. Out of those two pairs, which have been swapped if necessary, we accept that one where its second component is not yet included in the set  ${\mathcal S}$ that we found so far.We also impose a constraint replacing the number $n+1$ in that sequence of pairs by one.

To give some motivation; this problem appears in a natural way when considering the spectral moments of the sample correlation matrix in a Wishart random ensemble with $N$ time series of length $T$ each.

To illustrate the problem I took $n=3$ and I generated all possible permutations $\sigma$  along with their images $\sigma^{1,2}$. The index of the permutation, the permutation itself $\sigma$, the permutations $\sigma^1$ and $\sigma^2$ are shown in the first second, third and fourth column respectively. The fifth column shows the contribution to the spectral moment which reads $N^{\#(\sigma^1)-1} T^{\#(\sigma^2)-n} \prod\limits_{\xi=1}^{\#(\sigma^1)} M_{c^{\sigma^1}_\xi}$ where $\#(\sigma^{1,2})$ are the numbers of cycles of the permutations $\sigma^{1,2}$ and $(c^{\sigma^1}_\xi)_{\xi=1}^{\#(\sigma^1)}$ are the cycle lengths of the permutation $\sigma^1$. Finally $M_p := (\sum\limits_{j=1}^N \lambda_j^p)/W$ for $p=1,2,\cdots$ are the spectral moments of the underlying correlation matrix and $\left(\lambda_j\right)_{j=1}^N$ are the eigenvalues of that matrix.

[image]

Now, can we find all possible permutations $\sigma$ such that the triple ${\mathcal T}:=\left\{ \#(\sigma^1),\#(\sigma^2),(c^{\sigma^1}_\xi)_{\xi=1}^{\#(\sigma^1)}\right\}$ is fixed? For example if we take ${\mathcal T}=\left\{1,1,(3)\right\}$ then there are four permutations $\sigma$ that give rise to that triple namely the permutation $5,8,9,11$.

Comment: Is $\Pi_{2n}^{(2)}$ even a subgroup? I suppose it depends on what you mean by “composed of.”

Comment: Thank you for that. I haven't checked that. i changed subgroup to subset.

Comment: Definitely not a subgroup. $$\left[(12)(34)(56)\right]\left[(15)(24)(36)\right]=(164)(235)$$ (Using right-to-left composition.)

Comment: It is possible for $\lfloor \sigma_{j,1}/2\rfloor+1$ to be the same for two $j.$ For example, $(15)(24)(36).$ So $\sigma^1$ is not well-defined.

Comment: Until you make clear how $\sigma^1,\sigma^2$ can be made well-defined, there isn’t much we can do.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: My apologies for a late reply. Indeed, the old version of this question was not precise at all. I rewrote it to make it clearer. Now in case of (15)(24)(36) we have $\sigma^1 = ((1,2,3))$ and $\sigma^2 = ((1,3,2))$ i.e. the two new permutations have both one cycle of length three each.